# Call template function with typename combinations

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I want to loop over a "list of typenames" and look at all combinations of them. I was thinking of using a tuple for this, compare:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
void foo() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<T>::max() << ", " << std::numeric_limits<R>::max();
}

void call() {
    using int_types = std::tuple<int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t>;
    //Just to visualize my idea, this code does not work! (see comments)
    constexpr auto indices = std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, 8>();
    for (auto i: indices) {
        using T = std::tuple_element_t<i, int_types>;
        for (auto j: indices) {
            using R = std::tuple_element_t<j, int_types>;
            foo<T, R>();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course for loops are not consteval, thus this approach does not work. I think it might work using recursion or some consteval stuff from the STL but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: *Of course for loops are not consteval, thus this approach does not work.* Not sure you've understood what the actual problem here is. There is no consteval function in your code. And a consteval function can use loops. You can however not loop over a `integer_sequence`. It's an empty struct with no members. You use it for the type information in template contexts.

Comment: @super Thanks for clarifying, I just used it to visualize my problem and that all information is actually known at compile time. Could have just used a normal for loop instead I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand pack that way

```
using int_types = std::tuple<int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t,
                             int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t>;

[]<typename... Ts>(std::tuple<Ts...>){
    ([]<typename T, typename... Us>(std::type_identity<T>, std::tuple<Us...>){
        (foo<T, Us>(), ...);
    }(std::type_identity<Ts>{}, int_types{}), ...);
}(int_types{});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K7K9q3hPG)

Comment: LOL! This is so much more elegant than what I came up with +1. I just have to share my mess: [oups](https://godbolt.org/z/87WMWGqxx)

Comment: Beautiful, I never used variadic templates but I guess now is the time. Is there a similarly elegant way to still have access to the indices? For example, if I want to "remove" some combinations of T, R in the future.

Comment: Ted's version use index_sequence, and so have indice.

Comment: @Robin [Here's the same solution](https://godbolt.org/z/f1cb3W9n4) but with better formatting and some comments.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you! See, I have use for your "mess" ;) 
Could you please provide an example, when I want to exclude, for example, `i==j`, i.e. don't call foo if the types are equal.

Comment: @Robin I put a version of that up as an answer. Perhaps it helps someone :)

Comment: `i==j` is when **indexes** are equal, not necessary types ;-) for 
 type condition my version can still handle it: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eGa3cj1x5).

Comment: @Jarod42 ... yeah - and it's still clean. Very nice indeed!

Comment: You know what I meant Jarod :-) You two were very helpful, thanks! For the interested reader: I want to write unit-tests and check if my function behaves correctly for some combinations of these types. But as there are multiple template functions to test that's too much typing for me :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's an index based version where the inner lambda has access to the concrete indices, here `L` and `K`. In that you can do validation if you want to exclude calls to `foo` if the indices are equal for example:

```cpp
void call() {
   using int_types = std::tuple<int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t,
                                uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t>;

   constexpr auto tsize = std::tuple_size_v<int_types>;

   []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
      (  // fold 1
         []<size_t I, std::size_t... Js>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>,
                                         std::index_sequence<Js...>) 
         {
            ( // fold 2:
               []<std::size_t K, std::size_t L>(
                   std::integral_constant<std::size_t, K>,
                   std::integral_constant<std::size_t, L>)
               {
                        
                  if constexpr(K != L) foo<std::tuple_element_t<K, int_types>,
                                           std::tuple_element_t<L, int_types>>();

               }(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>(),
                 std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Js>()),
               ...);

         }(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>(),
           std::make_index_sequence<tsize>()),
         ...);
   }(std::make_index_sequence<tsize>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3qEh77aj8)